# From Spyder to Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio

I have decided to use Visual Studio instead of Spyder (Anaconda) yet a bunch of errors have occurred the moment I started. Does anybody know what is this all about?

```
& : The term 'C:\Users\vero pc\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was includ
ed, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\vero pc\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1:4 char:4
+ (& "C:\Users\vero pc\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell"  ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\vero p...ripts\conda.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Maybe the path of the anaconda executable is wrong, did you go to `'C:\Users\vero pc\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe'` to check if it is there? Also try to run it with admin priviliges.